# C++ constructor that deep copies a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, copy

I am a noob to C++ and programming in general and am trying to make a constructor which will duplicate a linked list. The idea is that I can use

```
 Individual* copyOfList = new Individual(originalList->getFirstBit());
```

to make a deep copy of the original list.

But my cose below seems not to be doing a deep copy. When I edit the `copyOfList` the `originalList` is affected as well. And I don't understand linked lists enough to make it deep copy. Can someone help me please.

```
Individual::Individual(BinaryNode * copyHead)
{
    head = copyHead;
    NodePtr last = NULL;
    NodePtr temp = NULL;
    curr = head;
    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        temp = new BinaryNode(curr->data, NULL);

        if (last != NULL)
        {
            last->next = temp;
        }

        last = temp;

        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = temp;
        }

        curr = curr->next;
    }
}
```

Here is the BinaryNode code

```
class BinaryNode
{
public:
BinaryNode();
BinaryNode(bool the_data, BinaryNode *next_link);

bool data;
BinaryNode *next;
private:
};
```

This is the original list code. I think the order I populated it is adding to the head.

```
if(the_length > 0)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int randnumber;
    NodePtr temp = new BinaryNode;
    for(int i = 0; i < the_length; i++)
    {
        randnumber=(rand() % 2);
        temp = new BinaryNode(randnumber,head);
        head = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide `BinaryNode` constructor. And why `head = copyHead;`?

Comment: What's `getFirstBit` do?

Comment: getFirstBit returns the pointer to the top of the original list.

Comment: Problem is that you are just updating the `head` every time causing memory leaks of the earlier allocation. Instead you need to allocate the next memory location to the child node (i.e., head->next).

Comment: And update the next node allocation accordingly.

Comment: *"The idea is that I can use 
 `Individual* copyOfList = new Individual(originalList->getFirstBit());`"* Thats a bad idea. **Don't use dynamic allocation when is not necesary** (That is, **don't declare/instance variables as in Java**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
head = copyHead;
```

With the above statement, `head` is pointing to the same memory location where `copyHead` is pointing to. Loop is not entered on an empty list. But in the loop -

```
if (head == NULL)
{
    head = temp;
}
```

This can never be the case on an linked list to be copied that has childs. So, you are never updating the `head` of the linked list and instead it is still pointing to the starting node of the linked list to be copied. Try -

```
Individual::Individual(BinaryNode * copyHead)
{
    if (NULL == copyHead)
    {
       // Empty list
       return;
    }

    head = new BinaryNode(copyHead->data, NULL);

    curr     = head;
    copyHead = copyHead->next;

    while (NULL != copyHead)
    {
        // Copy the child node
        curr->next     = new BinaryNode(copyHead->data, NULL);

        // Iterate to the next child element to be copied from.
        copyHead = copyHead->next;

        // Iterate to the next child element to be copied to.
        curr     = curr->next;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: your code makes way more sense but when i run it it seems to only copy the first list, but not the rest

Comment: Can you please show how the original list is populated ? Did you try to debug by printing all the node's data before copying the list ?

Comment: seems to be working thank you all, had been banging my head against the wall for ages :P

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `Individual` is a class in your code and basically it's holding the head possition of the list. I mean:

```
class Individual{
private:
void* head;// may be anything*
public:
void* getHead()
{
return head;
}
// all the methods
}
```

Now c++ provide a special type of constructor i.e. **Copy Constructor**. If you don't define a one compiler provide a default copy of copy constructor which do a shallow copy of a object. To define your custom copy constructor:
Firstly add a new method in `BinaryNode`:

```
void link(BinaryNode& b)
{
b.next=this;
}


    Individual::Individual(const Individual& args)
    {
    void* copyHead = args.getHead()
    if ( copyHead==nullptr)
        {
           // Empty list
           return;
        }

    head = new BinaryNode(copyHead->data, NULL);

    curr     = head->next;
    copyHead = copyHead->next;
    temp = head;
    while (NULL != copyHead)
    {
        // Copied the child node
        curr     = new BinaryNode(copyHead->data, NULL);
        curr.link(temp);
        temp = curr;

        // Iterate to the next child element to be copied from.
        copyHead = copyHead->next;

        // Iterate to the next child element to be copied to.
        curr     = curr->next;
    }
}
```

Now as you want to to a deep copy You have to implement a code that will copy the whole list starting from the head pointer.

Comment: Thanks for giving the credit. Are you sure my logic is correct :P

Comment: I just missed..... this code is not linking the head node to the later nodes.... It need a small fix @Mahesh

Comment: Oops. Good catch. I see what you are saying. Please see the edit.

Comment: args.getHead() is this the same function as my getFirstBit()? My function returns the pointer of head. If so can I use copyHead = args->getFirstBit()   ?

Comment: surely you can do that

Comment: what does this part do?  curr.link(temp);   is this making the pointer at the end of curr list the head of the temp list?

Comment: curr.link(temp) links the current node with temp node